# nvd3 not displaying graph for data with value of 1000 or higher

Tags: graph, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am tring to set up analytics for email campaigns with a discrete bar graph and I just found out that nvd3 has a weird bug where any data point with a value of 1000 or higher doesnt get rendered right.

here is the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/aMnSb/

```
 var data = [{
key: "Cumulative Return",
values: [
    {"label" : "delivered","value" : "999","color" : "458ec1",},{"label" : "opened","value" : "176","color" : "65a1cb",},{"label" : "clicked","value" : "8","color" : "7fb1d4",},{"label" : "unopened","value" : "487","color" : "aacce3",},{"label" : "bounced","value" : "357","color" : "eec4cc",},{"label" : "unsubscribed","value" : "1","color" : "e39ba9",},                 ]
```

}];

works , but this doesnt work

```
var data_large = [{
    key: "Cumulative Return",
    values: [
        {"label" : "delivered","value" : "1000","color" : "458ec1",},{"label" : "opened","value" : "176","color" : "65a1cb",},{"label" : "clicked","value" : "8","color" : "7fb1d4",},{"label" : "unopened","value" : "487","color" : "aacce3",},{"label" : "bounced","value" : "357","color" : "eec4cc",},{"label" : "unsubscribed","value" : "1","color" : "e39ba9",},                    ]
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this behaviour because the numbers in your JSON aren't actually numbers, but strings (enclosed in quotes). It works if you remove the quotes around the numbers in the JSON.

Comment: Thanks! Didnt think that would be an issue. Maybe they should do some parseInt magic in the library.

Comment: Actually it's better this way, since being more generic ensures that it can be used for more projects, albeit with a bit of work (creating some wrappers for data conversions typically).